# Reactor logging in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, project-reactor

I have a spring boot application with logging via `org.slf4j.Logger` and I have a `Mono` as seen below in a class in package `com.mycompanyname`.

```java
Mono
   .just("some text")
   .log(
       "category",
       Level.FINEST,
       SignalType.ON_SUBSCRIBE, SignalType.ON_NEXT, SignalType.ON_COMPLETE
   );
```

I set my logging in the *applicaton.yaml* like this:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    com.mycompanyname: TRACE
```

I would expect to see log statements if I subscribe to the `Mono` but I do not. For what package do I have to set the log level to `TRACE`?

If I change my config in the *application.yaml* to

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: TRACE
```

then I can see the log messages from my `Mono` stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the configuration in the application.yaml looks like this

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    com.mycompanyname: TRACE
```

then the logging in the `Mono` has to be defined like this:

```java
Mono
   .just("some text")
   .log(
       "com.mycompanyname.myclassname",
       Level.FINEST,
       SignalType.ON_SUBSCRIBE, SignalType.ON_NEXT, SignalType.ON_COMPLETE
   );
```

or

```java
Mono
   .just("some text")
   .log(
       this.getClass().getName(),
       Level.FINEST,
       SignalType.ON_SUBSCRIBE, SignalType.ON_NEXT, SignalType.ON_COMPLETE
   );
```

The `category` parameter of the `log` method has to match the logging configuration name.